# Connection trouble GeoExt to Geoserver Layer

Tags: postgis, geoext

I'm so sorry for my english, it's not the best. I'm trying to modify my postgres geographic table with this code:

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.ashx?url=";
    var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.1.0",
            url: "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wfs",
            featurePrefix: "ST",
            featureType: "geofenceprueba",
            featureNS: "http://www.safetracker.com/catalogLayer",
            geometryName: "geom"//,
            //maxFeatures:100,
            //schema: "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&;typename=ST:geofenceprueba",
            //srsName: "EPSG:4326"
        })
    });

    var store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
        fields: [
          {
              name: "name",
              type: "string"
          },
        {
            name: "aliases1",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "idtype",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "id",
            type: "int",
            defaultValue: 0
        }
        ],
        layer: layer,
        addFeatureFilter: function (feature) {
            return feature.state !== OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
        }
    });


    var modifyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(layer);


    var gridPanel = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        title: "Feature Table - Medford Parks",
        region: "center",
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
        },
        store: store,
        listeners: {
            afteredit: function (e) {
                var feature = e.record.get("feature");
                if (feature.state !== OpenLayers.State.INSERT) {
                    feature.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
                }
            }
        },
        sm: new GeoExt.grid.FeatureSelectionModel({
            selectControl: modifyControl.selectControl,
            singleSelect: true
        }),

        cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            defaults: {
                sortable: true,
                editor: {
                    xtype: "textfield"
                }
            },
            columns: [
              {
                  header: "Name",
                  dataIndex: "name"
              },
            {
                header: "Owner",
                dataIndex: "aliases1"
            },
            {
                header: "Usage",
                dataIndex: "idtype",
                width: 35
            },
            {
                xtype: "id",
                header: "# of Facilities",
                dataIndex: "id",
                format: "1,000",
                align: "right",
                width: 55,
                editor: {
                    xtype: "numberfield"
                }
            }
            ]
        })
    });

    var drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
        handlerOptions: {
            multi: true
        }
    });

    var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        title: "Map",
        region: "west",
        width: 400,
        layers: [layer],
        extent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-122.91, 42.28, -122.76, 42.41),
        bbar: [
          new GeoExt.Action({
              control: drawControl,
              text: "Create",
              enableToggle: true
          }),
        {
            text: "Delete",
            handler: function () {
                gridPanel.getSelectionModel().each(function (rec) {
                    var feature = rec.get("feature");
                    modifyControl.unselectFeature(feature);
                    gridPanel.store.remove(rec);
                    if (feature.state !== OpenLayers.State.INSERT) {
                        feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
                        layer.addFeatures([feature]);
                    }
                })
            }
        }, "->",
        {
            text: "Save",
            handler: function () {
                store.commitChanges();
                saveStrategy.save();
            }
        }
        ]

    });

    mapPanel.map.addControl(modifyControl);
    modifyControl.activate();

    // var modifyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(layer);
    // mapPanel.map.addControl(modifyControl);
    // modifyControl.activate();
    mapPanel.map.addControl(drawControl);

    var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: "map-id",
        layout: "border",
        height: 450,
        width: 800,
        items: [gridPanel, mapPanel]
    });


});
```

I have a proxy in my .net web application:

using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Web;

/// 
 /// adapted from: http://code.google.com/p/iisproxy
 /// 
 public class proxy : IHttpHandler
 {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string usuario = "admin";
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        string remoteUrl = request.QueryString["url"];

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl);
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    req.Method = request.HttpMethod;
    req.ContentType = request.ContentType;
    req.UserAgent = request.UserAgent;

    var basicPwd = "geoserver";
    req.Credentials = basicPwd == null ? CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials : new NetworkCredential(usuario, basicPwd);

    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    req.Headers["Remote-User"] = usuario;
    foreach (string each in request.Headers)
        if (!WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(each) && each != "Remote-User")
            req.Headers.Add(each, request.Headers.Get(each));
    if (request.HttpMethod == "POST") {
        System.IO.Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        CopyStream(request.InputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.Close();
    }

    HttpWebResponse response;
    try {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    } catch (WebException we) {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
        if (response == null) {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 13;
            context.Response.Write("Could not contact back-end site");
            context.Response.End();
            return;
        }
    }

    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    context.Response.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
    context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
    foreach (string each in response.Headers)
        if (each != "Location" && !WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(each))
            context.Response.AddHeader(each, response.Headers.Get(each));

    CopyStream(response.GetResponseStream(), context.Response.OutputStream);
    response.Close();
    context.Response.End();
}

static public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    //updated to read gzip compressed streams correctly
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    while (true) {
        int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (read <= 0)
            return;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
public bool IsReusable {
    get { return false; }
}
```

}

I have already checked my namespace and workspace names, everything looks ok but I don't know what's wrong, Could somebody help me with this code?

---

The proxy works fine.
The problem was at this code line:

```
            xtype: "id",
            header: "# of Facilities",
            dataIndex: "id",
            format: "1,000",
            align: "right",
            width: 55,
            editor: {
                xtype: "numberfield"
            }
```

xtype value have to be allowed feature (numbercolumn).

Right Now I'm trying to save changes for the new geometries but I got an exception here:
   saveStrategy.save();
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null